# what is the maximum number of responses a places request will return?

Tags: google-maps

When I go to google maps and search for "DPM" I get 2,314 responses.   When I use the following places request, I only get 30.   What am I doing wrong?

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=41.983333,-87.766666&radius=5000&sensor=false&type=doctor&name=DPM&key=*myKey*

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/) (with my emphasis):

> An XML response consists of a single `<PlaceSearchResponse>` and three top-level elements:
>       * `<status>` contains metadata on the request. See Status Codes below.
>       * Zero or more `<result>` elements, each containing information about a single establishment. See Place Search Results for information about these results. **The Places API returns up to 20 establishment results**. Additionally, political  results, or streets, may be returned which serve to identify the area of the request.
>       * html_attributions contain a set of attributions about this listing which must be displayed to the user.

You're not doing anything wrong, necessarily.

Comment: Thank you Andrew, I read/know that too.  However, when I search google maps on its page, I get so many more as I wrote originally.   How can I get those too?

Comment: You can't. Google doesn't restrict its own maps, but the Places *API* is restricted so that others can't build competing services.